# Not able to install OCRPaddle for WIndows

Tags: python, ocr, paddle-paddle, paddleocr

I'm trying to install the PaddleOCR package following the [Quick Start Guide](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/release/2.6/doc/doc_en/quickstart_en.md). When I run this command to install PaddleOCR Whl Package:

```html
pip install "paddleocr>=2.0.1" # Recommend to use version 2.0.1+
```

I'm getting this error when building the Poligon3 wheel:

```html
  Building wheel for Polygon3 (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      Using NumPy extension!
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Polygon
      copying Polygon\IO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Polygon
      copying Polygon\Shapes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Polygon
      copying Polygon\Utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Polygon
      copying Polygon\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Polygon
      running build_ext
      building 'Polygon.cPolygon' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for Polygon3
  Running setup.py clean for Polygon3
Failed to build Polygon3
Installing collected packages: Polygon3, lmdb, zipp, typing-extensions, tifffile, shapely, scipy, rapidfuzz, PyWavelets, python-dateutil, pyparsing, pycryptodome, opencv-python, opencv-contrib-python, networkx, MarkupSafe, lxml, itsdangerous, imageio, future, fonttools, et-xmlfile, dill, cython, cycler, cssselect, colorama, cachetools, Babel, attrdict, Werkzeug, tqdm, pandas, packaging, openpyxl, multiprocess, kiwisolver, Jinja2, importlib-metadata, bce-python-sdk, scikit-image, matplotlib, cssutils, click, premailer, imgaug, flask, Flask-Babel, visualdl, paddleocr
  Running setup.py install for Polygon3 ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for Polygon3 did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      Using NumPy extension!
      running install
      C:\Users\jd\miniconda3\envs\ocrpaddle\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Polygon
      copying Polygon\IO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Polygon
      copying Polygon\Shapes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Polygon
      copying Polygon\Utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Polygon
      copying Polygon\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\Polygon
      running build_ext
      building 'Polygon.cPolygon' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> Polygon3

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

Has anyone encountered this problem? I'm using a conda environment with Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly mentioned that you need to install "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or above"

Please install it and you are good to go.